# User Deprecated: Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader is deprecated

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am using Symfony 3.4.12 and can't find any information about how to solve this deprecation:

```
User Deprecated: Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader is deprecated.
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `Doctrine Common` package will be split into small packages and the `ClassLoader` component will be dropped, that's why the deprecation notice. 
See https://github.com/doctrine/common/issues/826 and https://www.doctrine-project.org/2018/07/12/common-2-9-and-dbal-2-8-and-orm-2-6-2.html.

If you are using the package `doctrine/common` directly then the solution would be to remove that dependency and add the individual packages instead. 
If you are using Symfony there is already a PR to change that: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/27609. So in any new version, the deprecation should be gone.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But should I do now something to remove this deprication?

Comment: For now I think there is nothing you can do by yourself. However after symfony releases a new version which includes the PR on my answer, the deprecation notice should automatically go away.

Comment: Great! Many Thanks!

Comment: This is very tormentor.

Comment: If you [mark tests as legacy](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html#mark-tests-as-legacy) then the deprecation notice will be ignored, so your CI won't fail. The easiest way is adding the `@group legacy` annotation.

Comment: 2018 get still this warning

Comment: My logs are spammed by this message, how can I suppress it temporarily?

Comment: using symfony 4.1.7 but still getting this error. :(

Comment: symfony 4.2.2 and still there :(

Answer (score 1):

In this case (https://pasteboard.co/HJOKbzk.png), we have 2 ways:

**- when running phpunit in console set environment variable**, like this:

```
$ SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER=weak ./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

show simple notice in result: `Remaining deprecation notices (1)` (https://pasteboard.co/HJONdvJ.png)

besides, we can use this option:

```
$ SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER=weak_vendors ./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

we will get a more strict warning (https://pasteboard.co/HJOOZH9.png)

**- we can also add a variable to the phpunit configuration** (phpunit.xml[.dist])

```
<phpunit ...>
    <php>
        ...
        <env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="weak_vendors" />
```

Comment: To omit all the deprecated messages (caution with this): `<env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="disabled" />`